# What issues arise with Clustering $\rightarrow$ PCA $\rightarrow$ Linear regression?

Tags: regression, clustering, pca

In the last couple of weeks I have been reading about regression and I wanted to get some feedback on this idea since I have not found any material covering it.

Imagine a non-linear function $y = f(X)$ that maps inputs $X$ from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $y$ in $\mathbb{R}$, where $n \geq 1$. It should be possible to linearly interpolate the values of the function in a small enough region of the domain. If I unevenly sample values of $f(X)$ along $X$, I should try to interpolate among points in $X$ that are closer together since they might map to similar values of $y$ (especially if $f(X)$ is smooth enough).

An algorithm to carry out the previously mentioned procedure would be:

1. Apply clustering algorithm to find regions in space with high density of points.
2. Use PCA to find the coordinates that better explain the data.
3. Linearly interpolate using the axes provided by PCA.

For carrying out regression one would assign a given point $X'$ to an existing cluster, use the coordinates from PCA and obtain an approximation of $f(X')$

What issues would you anticipate with this? Do you think it would work?